# Having trouble adding items to a WPF ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I've got a simple application connected to a SQL Server database, and I'm trying to pull data from the server to add it to a WPF `ListView`. I've done what I thought was the hard part of that, and successfully pulled the data - confirmed that already. But when I try to add it to my existing listview, the listview remains blank. Here's the code I've got to add it.

`GetEmployees` uses a middle tier class to connect to the database and retrieve the properties of an Employee. It successfully creates all of these variables and assigns them values from the database. The bottom line - `lvwEmpSearch.Items.Add(emp);` is what does not work.

Edit: Code is adjusted.

Code for adding to the listview:

```
public ObservableCollection<EmployeeViewModel> Employees { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<EmployeeViewModel>();

private void btnFindAllEmployees_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        List<Employee> empList = GetEmployees();
        foreach (Employee emp in empList)
        {
            var model = new EmployeeViewModel
            {
                empID = emp._empID,
                Name = emp._fName + " " + emp._lName,
                Address = emp._address + ", " + emp._city + ", " + emp._state + " " + emp._zip,
                HireDate = emp._doH,
                Phone = emp._phone,
                PayRate = emp._payRate,
                Email = emp._email,
            };
            Employees.Add(model);
        }
    }
```

EmployeeViewModel class:

```
public class EmployeeViewModel
{
    public int empID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public DateTime HireDate { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public decimal PayRate { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: You should create an underlying view model collection and bind it to the list view.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with all those variables in the foreach. And why do you not use the Properties to read the values?

Comment: Try using an ObservableCollection. This collection will update the binding when the collection is changed. Bind this collection to your Listview, instead of trying to add them directly to your listview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a ViewModel to hold the item information you want displayed.

Based on column binding you are looking for something like

```
public class EmployeeViewModel {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public DateTime HireDate { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public decimal PayRate { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Create an observable collection to hold the items

```
public ObservableCollection<EmployeeViewModel> Employees { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<EmployeeViewModel>();
```

and to allow the view to bind to the list

```
<ListView  x:Name="lvwEmpSearch"  ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}" >
    <!-- ...removed for brevity -->
</ListView>
```

Now all that is needed is to populate the collection within the main ViewModel

```
List<Employee> empList = GetEmployees();
foreach (Employee emp in empList) {
    var model = new EmployeeViewModel {
        ID = emp._empID,
        Name = emp._fName + " " + emp._lName,
        Address = emp._address + ", " + emp._city + ", " + emp._state + " " + emp._zip,
        HireDate = emp._doH,
        Phone = emp._phone,
        PayRate = emp._payRate,
        Email = emp._email,
    };
    Employees.Add(model);
}
```

You seem to be doing everything in the code behind so you would need to bind the view. The initial assumption was that you were following the MVVM pattern.

```
//CTOR
public EmployeesView() {
    this.InitializeComponents();
    this.Employees = new ObservableCollection<EmployeeViewModel>();
    //Bind the view so that 
    this.DataContext = this;
}

public ObservableCollection<EmployeeViewModel> Employees { get; private set; }

private void btnFindAllEmployees_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    //...code removed for brevity
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the following:

In your view:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}">
      <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
          <GridViewColumn Header="ID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ID}"></GridViewColumn>
          <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"></GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
      </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

In your code behind of the view:

```
 public MainWindow() {
  InitializeComponent();

  DataContext = new MainViewModel();
}
```

The MainViewModel code:

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {
public MainViewModel() {
  FEmployees = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();
  FEmployees.Add(new Employee {ID = 1,Name="Jordy van Eijk"});
  FEmployees.Add(new Employee {ID = 2,Name="John Doe"});
  FEmployees.Add(new Employee {ID = 3,Name="Jane Doe"});
}

private ObservableCollection<Employee> FEmployees;

public ObservableCollection<Employee> Employees {
  get { return FEmployees; }
  set {
    FEmployees = value;
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Employees));
  }
}


public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

[NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string APropertyName = null) {
  PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(APropertyName));
}
}

public class Employee {
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why all the PropertyChanged stuff when the Collection itself doesn't have to change? You only change the items in the collection. You can make the ObservableCollection readonly.

Comment: @PeterBruins this is just a standard viewmodel which i use... The property changed is not needed here because of the ObservableCollection en not having to set the the complete List.. Never use Plublic Setters on a list but make it a private setter. This was just a quick setup

Comment: "Never use Plublic Setters on a list but make it a private setter" You just made a public setter on your list...

Answer (score -1):

Youshould be able to create an ObservableCollection containing your employees and bind them to the ItemsSource.

```
private ObservableCollection<Employee> _employees = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();
public ObservableCollection<Employee> Employees
{
    get { return _employees; }
    protected set
    {
        if (_employees == value)
            return;
        _employees = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Employees");
    }
}
```

And bind it like this:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}"/>
```

And in code you could fill it with:

```
Employees.AddRange(GetEmployees());
```

Comment: That complicated setter is not needed, because the collection itself never changes, only the items in the collection. Best to replace the first block of code with this: `public ObservableCollection<Employee> Employees {get; private set} = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();`

Comment: I do it either way because it is cleaner and the Collection might change at some point. I had Problems with that in the past.

Comment: Data like this can change while the program is running so there might be the need to reload the Data in the future so why not prepare for it. And your method is not readonly it is private set.

Comment: When you reload the data you can clear your list and use AddRange(), no need to create a new list.

Comment: I never had an instance where Clear() did what I wanted it to so it was easier to just make a new instance.